Parsing json output with JQ - Searching for patterns
I have the following JSON (based on NDPI output)
{
    "src_ip": "x.x.x.x",
    "dest_ip": "x1.x1.x1.x1",
    "src_port": 48318,
    "dst_port": 443,
    "ip": 4,
    "proto": "TCP",
    "ndpi": {
        "flow_risk": {
            "35": {
                "risk": "Susp Entropy",
                "severity": "Medium",
                "risk_score": {
                    "total": 210,
                    "client": 165,
                    "server": 45
                }
            }
        },
        "confidence": {
            "1": "Match by port"
        },
        "proto": "TLS",
        "proto_id": "91",
        "proto_by_ip": "Unknown",
        "proto_by_ip_id": 0,
        "encrypted": 1,
        "breed": "Safe",
        "category_id": 5,
        "category": "Web"
    },
    "detection_completed": 1,
    "check_extra_packets": 0,
    "flow_id": 0,
    "first_seen": 1733074272.824,
    "last_seen": 1733074282.757,
    "duration": 9.933,
    "vlan_id": 0,
    "bidirectional": 1,
    "xfer": {
        "data_ratio": -0.958,
        "data_ratio_str": "Download",
        "src2dst_packets": 1268,
        "src2dst_bytes": 86239,
        "src2dst_goodput_bytes": 2551,
        "dst2src_packets": 2693,
        "dst2src_bytes": 4042956,
        "dst2src_goodput_bytes": 3865218
    },
    "iat": {
        "flow_min": 1,
        "flow_avg": 6.1,
        "flow_max": 4005,
        "flow_stddev": 108.3,
        "c_to_s_min": 0,
        "c_to_s_avg": 7.4,
        "c_to_s_max": 4005,
        "c_to_s_stddev": 137.8,
        "s_to_c_min": 0,
        "s_to_c_avg": 1.4,
        "s_to_c_max": 35,
        "s_to_c_stddev": 2.2
    },
    "pktlen": {
        "c_to_s_min": 66,
        "c_to_s_avg": 68.0,
        "c_to_s_max": 514,
        "c_to_s_stddev": 28.8,
        "s_to_c_min": 66,
        "s_to_c_avg": 1501.3,
        "s_to_c_max": 1506,
        "s_to_c_stddev": 76.6
    },
    "tcp_flags": {
        "cwr_count": 0,
        "ece_count": 0,
        "urg_count": 0,
        "ack_count": 3961,
        "psh_count": 1323,
        "rst_count": 0,
        "syn_count": 0,
        "fin_count": 0,
        "src2dst_cwr_count": 0,
        "src2dst_ece_count": 0,
        "src2dst_urg_count": 0,
        "src2dst_ack_count": 1268,
        "src2dst_psh_count": 7,
        "src2dst_rst_count": 0,
        "src2dst_syn_count": 0,
        "src2dst_fin_count": 0,
        "dst2src_cwr_count": 0,
        "dst2src_ece_count": 0,
        "dst2src_urg_count": 0,
        "dst2src_ack_count": 2693,
        "dst2src_psh_count": 1316,
        "dst2src_rst_count": 0,
        "dst2src_syn_count": 0,
        "dst2src_fin_count": 0
    },
    "c_to_s_init_win": 0,
    "s_to_c_init_win": 0
}

I can get almost all the information (src_ip, ports, etc.), but there is one thing related to "flow_risk"
{"flow_risk": {"35": {"risk":"Susp Entropy","severity":"Medium"

that is related to the number (in this case 35). This number can be different (from 01 to 50) and I don't know how to filter to search for different numbers.
Right now, this is the filter I'm using
cat data.json | jq -r '"\(.src_ip),\(.src_port),\(.dest_ip),\(.dst_port),\(.proto),\(.ndpi.proto),\(.ndpi.category),\(.ndpi.hostname),\(.duration),\(.vlan_id),\(.xfer.src2dst_bytes),\(.xfer.dst2src_bytes),\(.ndpi.flow_risk."35".risk),\(.ndpi.flow_risk."35".severity)"')

This works when the number is exactly 35, but is there any chance to use something like wildcards with jQ?
I mean how can I do this to accept multiple numbers? (for ex: searching from 01 to 50?)
Something like
\(.ndpi.flow_risk."*".risk),\(.ndpi.flow_risk."*".severity)"')

thanks !

Thanks @pmf for your quick replay and I'm sorry for the format. How can I assign multiple values to "$n" ? (I mean to search for 1,2,3....50) ?

To access a variable but known key, use the --arg flag to bind a variable to a value, and then .[$varname] to access the field:
jq -r --arg n "35" '… .ndpi.flow_risk[$n].risk …'


is there any chanve to use something like wildcards with jq ?

To access all keys, just use .[]. However, you presumably want to reference the same keys both times you've used 35 in the example. For that, iterate before creating (the relevant part of) the output string, and reference the iteration value (context):
jq -r '… ,\(.ndpi.flow_risk[] | "\(.risk),\(.severity)")'

To access a specific range, use range to create them, turn it into a string using tostring, and proceed as above ("0" + prepends the zero, and [-2:] reduces it to the last two characters):
jq -r '… ,\(.ndpi.flow_risk[range (50)+1 | ("0" + tostring)[-2:]] | "\(.risk),\(.severity)")'


That part of the filter can be represented in multiple ways, but in my experience one of the easier ways to work with the keys of an object involves to_entries.
As an example, you can use something along the lines of .ndpi.flow_risk | to_entries[] | select(.key | tonumber | . <= 50 and . >= 0).value | "\(.risk),\(.severity)" to get for those last two pieces of information (if the "flow risk" object is guaranteed to have only a single key, which is guaranteed to be numeric)
